# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion

Tags: java, sql, hive, hiveql

I wrote a script to orchestrate a query on our hive cluster. And this is the place where the error happened:

```
Result<Record> result = client.doWithRetry(new SQLClient.JooqSQLFunction<Result<Record>>() {
                @Override
                public Result<Record> apply(Connection conn, DSLContext jooq) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                    return jooq.fetch(String.format(
                            "select s.name as season_name, r.name as round_name, " +
                            " g.uuid, g.name, g.create_time, "+
                            " (select count(*) from picks_questions q where q.round_uuid=r.uuid) as questions_in_round, "+
                            " (select group_concat(du.yinz_id) from drops_entries e inner join drops_users du on du.uuid=e.user_uuid where g.uuid=e.drop_uuid and e.create_time<r.end_time) as member_yinz_ids, "+
                            " (select count(*) from drops_entries e inner join drops_users du on du.uuid=e.user_uuid where g.uuid=e.drop_uuid and e.create_time<r.end_time) as member_count, "+
                            " (select count(*) from drops_messages m where m.drop_uuid=g.uuid and m.send_time>=r.start_time and m.send_time<r.end_time) as messages_sent "+
                            " from picks_seasons s "+
                            " inner join picks_rounds r on r.season_uuid=s.uuid "+
                            " inner join drops g on g.create_time<r.end_time "+
                            " where g.name not like 'ADMIN_DROP:%' and g.name<>'' "+
                            " and s.uuid in "+
                            " ( "+
                            " select uuid from picks_seasons "+
                            " where "+
                            " unix_timestamp('%s') >= unix_timestamp(start_time) " +
                            " AND " +
                            " unix_timestamp('%s') < unix_timestamp(end_time) " +
                            " );",
                        sqlDTF.print(seg.getStartingInstant()),
                        sqlDTF.print(seg.getEndingInstant())
                    ));
                }
            }
```

I didn't use "'''" at all. Any ideas what went wrong?

Error Traceback:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''

at workflows.AbstractCopperWorkflow.main(AbstractCopperWorkflow.java:394) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

% Mark is a reserved character in format string of Java. To escape this, we should use `%%` instead of `%`.